# why JavaScript form works in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

i need following function to be execute in Firefox.., but it is working fine in chrome. the problem was when i do 'Inspect Element With Firebug' it is working fine. the method 'EditEncounterBillStatus' is also hitting correctly. but when i don't use 'Inspect Element With Firebug' the method EditEncounterBillStatus is not hitting.. i tried a lot to sort out this. but still i can't can any one help me to find solution thanks in advance.

```
  else if (element.trim() == "Approved") {
            var TestPin = prompt("Please Enter your PIN");
            if (TestPin != null) {
                if (isNaN(TestPin)) {
                    alert("Please Enter a Valid Pin");
                    return;
                }
                else if (TestPin == pin) {
                    var postVisitData = { VisitId: vid};
                    $.post("/Emr/WaitingRoom/EditEncounterBillStatus", { VisitId: vid }, function (data) {
                    });

                    window.location = "/Emr/Patients/Show?PID=" + pid;
                }
                else {
                    alert("Your Entered PIN Is Incorrect");
                }
            }
            else {
                return;
            }
        }
```

Comment: chances are you are effectively cancelling the `$.post` by changing the `window.location` in the line after performing the `$.post` - the fact that it `works` in chrome is perhaps accidental

Comment: So how can i rectify it

Comment: as per the answer :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change location upon the success of the `post` call, so put that in your callback function body:

```
$.post("/Emr/WaitingRoom/EditEncounterBillStatus", { VisitId: vid },
      function (data) {
                window.location = "/Emr/Patients/Show?PID=" + pid;
      });
```

This way you are sure you only change location when the `post` action was executed. Otherwise you risk that you change location before the `post` happens. In debug mode, and certainly when you step through the code, there is enough time for the `post` to finish in time, and so your original code then works.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend doing it like this

```
            else if (TestPin == pin) {
                $.post("/Emr/WaitingRoom/EditEncounterBillStatus", { VisitId: vid }, function (data) {
                    window.location = "/Emr/Patients/Show?PID=" + pid;
                });
                return; // in case of side effects in unseen code
            }
```

i.e. wait until the $.post has finished before changing the window.location

As the rest of your code is unseen there could be side effects of performing this in this way - hence the return where it is - but even then, not knowing the full call stack there could still be side effects - you have been warned